# I can't get my images to show in my sliding blocks javascript assignment

Tags: javascript

I am working on a homework assignment for a javascript course. The assignment is to display a sliding block puzzle. The pieces are laid out in a grid with one blank space. Pieces adjacent to the blank space can be swapped with the space. The goal of the puzzle is to move the block into their correct positions.

I cannot get my images to show up in the grid. I have been staring at my code and cannot figure out where I went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Here is my code, HTML first, followed by my two external javascript files.

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 15
   Review Assignment

   Kiddergarden Sliding Blocks Puzzle
   Author: Collin Klopstein
   Date: December 5, 2013   

   Filename:         blocks.htm
   Supporting files: block0.jpg - block23.jpg, kgmenu.jpg, kgtitle.jpg, library.js,
                     photo.jpg, sbtitle.jpg, sbblocks.css, slideblocks.js

-->

   <title>Today's Sliding Blocks Puzzle Puzzle</title>
   <link href="sbblocks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="library.js"</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="slideblocks.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
   <form id="sb" action="">

   <div id="head">
      <img src="kgtitle.jpg" alt="Kiddergarden" />
   </div>
   <div id="menu">
      <img src="kgmenu.jpg" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div id="title">
      <img src="sbtitle.jpg" alt="Sliding Blocks" />
   </div>

   <div id="slidingBlocks">
      <div id="block0" class="block"></div><div id="block1" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block2" class="block"></div><div id="block3" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block4" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block5" class="block"></div><div id="block6" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block7" class="block"></div><div id="block8" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block9" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block10" class="block"></div><div id="block11" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block12" class="block"></div><div id="block13" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block14" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block15" class="block"></div><div id="block16" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block17" class="block"></div><div id="block18" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block19" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block20" class="block"></div><div id="block21" class="block"></div>
      <div id="block22" class="block"></div><div id="block23" class="block"></div>
      <div id="blank" class="block"></div>
   </div>


   <div id="main">
      <p><img src="photo.jpg" alt="" style="float: right; margin: 0px 0px 6px 6px" />
         Click the <kbd>Scramble</kbd> button and try to reassemble the photo shown
         at the right by 
         swapping a block adjacent to the one blank space in the puzzle. 
         To solve the puzzle, click the 
         <kbd>Solve</kbd> button.</p>

      <h2>For Mouse Users</h2>
      <p>To swap a block with the blank space, click a block adjacent to the blank 
         space.</p>
      <h2>For Keyboard Users</h2> 
      <p>Use your <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> to highlight different puzzle blocks. When adjacent 
         to the blank space, press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key to swap the selected 
         block with the blank space.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="controls">
      <p>
         <input type="button" id="scramble" value="Scramble" />
         <input type="button" id="solve" value="Solve" />
      </p>
   </div>

   <address>
      Kiddergarden &#183;
      A safe site on the Web for kids and families
   </address>
   </div>



   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

library.js:

```
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML, and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 15
   Tutorial Case

   Author: Collin Klopstein   
   Date: December 5, 2013     
   Filename: library.js



   Functions List:

   scrambleIt()
      Reloads the current Web page, thus re-arranging the puzzle blocks

   solveIt()
      Places the puzzle blocks in the correct order in the puzzle

   getStyle(object, styleName)
      Returns the computed style value for a specified styleName applied to
      an object.

   nextTo(object1, object)
      Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the coordinate (x, y) lies
      within the boundaries of object

   withinIt(x, y, object2)
      Returns a Boolean value indicating whether object2 is next to object1
      (either above, below, to the left, or to the right of object1)

   swapObjects(object1, object2)
      Swaps the page positions of object1 and object2

   scrambleIntegers(size)
      Returns an array of integers from 0 up to size-1 sorted in random order
      with even parity observed in the sorting of the integers (to ensure
      a solveable solution of the sliding blocks puzzle.)

   randOrder()
      Returns a random value between -0.5 and 0.5

   addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap)
      Assigns an event handers to object where evName is the name of the event,
      fnName is the name of the function, and cap is the capture phase.
      This function works for both the IE and W3C event models.

   removeEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap)  
      Removes an event handers from object where evName is the name of the event,
      fnName is the name of the function, and cap is the capture phase.
      This function works for both the IE and W3C event models.

*/

function scrambleIt() {
   window.location.reload();
}

function solveIt() {
   for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
      blocks[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(block"+i+".jpg)";
   }
}

function getStyle(object, styleName) {
   if (window.getComputedStyle) {
      return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(object, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
   } else if (object.currentStyle) {
      return object.currentStyle[styleName]
   }
}

function nextTo(object1, object2) {

   var x = parseInt(object1.style.left) + 5;
   var y = parseInt(object1.style.top) + 5;

   width = parseInt(object2.style.width);
   height = parseInt(object2.style.height);

   // check if object is located above object1
   if (withinIt(x,y-height,object2)) {return true};

   // check if object is located to the left of object1
   if (withinIt(x-width,y,object2)) {return true};

   // check if object is located below object1
   if (withinIt(x,y+height,object2)) {return true};

   // check if object is located to the right of object1
   if (withinIt(x+width,y,object2)) {return true};

   return false;   
}

function withinIt(x, y, object) {
   var within = false;

   var left = parseInt(object.style.left);
   var top = parseInt(object.style.top);
   var width = parseInt(object.style.width);
   var height = parseInt(object.style.height);

   var bottom = top + height;
   var right = left + width;

   if ((x >= left && x <= right) && (y >= top && y <= bottom)) within = true;

   return within;
}

function swapObjects(object1, object2) {
   var tempTop = object2.style.top;
   var tempLeft = object2.style.left;

   object2.style.top = object1.style.top;
   object2.style.left = object1.style.left;
   object1.style.top = tempTop;
   object1.style.left = tempLeft;
}

function scrambleIntegers(size) {
  var x = new Array(size);
  for (var i = 0;i < x.length;i++) {x[i] = i;}
  x.sort(randOrder);

  var nSum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length;i++) {
     for (var j = i; j < x.length; j++) {if (x[j] < x[i]) nSum++;}
  }

  if (Math.floor(nSum/2) != nSum/2) { 
     // puzzle is not solveable make one more swap of values
     needSwap = true;
     for (var i = 0; (i < x.length) && needSwap; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < x.length && needSwap; j++) {
           if (x[j] > x[i]) {temp=x[j];x[j]=x[i];x[i]=temp;needSwap=false;}
        }
     }
  }
  return x;
}

function randOrder(){
   return 0.5 - Math.random();
}

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.attachEvent)
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.addEventListener)
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function removeEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.detachEvent)
        object.detachEvent("on", evName, fnName);
    else if (object.removeEventListener)
        object.removeEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}
```

slideblocks.js:

```
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML, and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 15
   Review Assignment

   Author: Collin Klopstein  
   Date: December 5, 2013    

   Filename: slideblocks.js


   Global Variables List;

   blocks
      An array of elements belonging to the block class

   blankBlock
      The puzzle representing a blank space in the sliding block puzzle

   keyBlock
      The puzzle block currently selected by the user's keyboard


   Functions List:
   init()
      Sets up and initializes the Web page, defining the blocks array,
      and appying event handlers to mouse and keyboard actions

   swapWithBlank(e)
      Responds to the mousedown event to swap the current block with an adjacent
      blank space (if one exists)

   highlightBlank(e)
      Highlights a block on the mouseover event by changing the mouse cursor if the block
      is adjacent to a blank space 

   removeHighlightBlank(e)
      Removes highlighting from a puzzle block by changing the cursor style to "default".

   keySwapWithBlank()
      Swaps keyBlock with an adjacent blank space (if one exists)

   selectBlock(diffX, diffY)
      Moves the keyBlock diffX to the right and diffY down.

   keyEvent(e)
      Responds to the spacebar event to swap keyBlock with an adjacent blank
      space or to arrow keys to move the position of keyBlock up, down, to
      the left, or to the right

*/

var blocks = new Array();
var blankBlock;
var keyBlock;


window.onload = init;

function init() {
   var allElem = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for (var i = 0; i < allElem.length; i++) {
      if (allElem[i].className == "block") blocks.push(allElem[i]);
   }

   var randomIntegers = scrambleIntegers(blocks.length - 1);//sets var to scrambleIntegers() w/ parameter one less than blocks
   for ( var i = 0; i < blocks.length - 1; i++) {
        blocks[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(block" + randomIntegers[i] + ".jpg)";
        addEvent(blocks[i], "click", swapWithBlank, false);//calls swapWithBlank when block is clicked
        addEvent(blocks[i], "mouseover", highlightBlank, false);//calls highlightBlank when mouse moves over block
        addEvent(blocks[i], "mouseout", removeHighlightBlank, false);//call removeHighlighBlank when mouse moves away from block
    }

   for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
      blocks[i].style.top = getStyle(blocks[i], "top");
      blocks[i].style.left = getStyle(blocks[i], "left");
      blocks[i].style.width = getStyle(blocks[i], "width");
      blocks[i].style.height = getStyle(blocks[i], "height");
   }

   blankBlock = blocks[24];//equal to last element of blocks array
   keyBlock = blocks[0];//equal to first element of blocks array
   addEvent(document, "keydown", keyEvent, false);//add event keydown that occurs when user presses key

}

function swapWithBlank(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;//points to event object
    var mouseBlock = evt.target || evt.srcElement;//references target source of event

    if (nextTo(mouseBlock, blankBlock))
        swapObjects(mouseBlock, blankBlock);//uses nextto() to test if mouseBlock is next to blankBlock, if so calls swapObjects()
}

function highlightBlank(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;//points to event object
    var mouseBlock = evt.target || evt.srcElement;//references target source of event

    if (nextTo(mouseBlock, blankBlock))
        document.style.cursor = "pointer";//sets cursor to pointer if mouseBlock is next to blankBlock
}

function removeHighlightBlank(e) {
    //remove highlighting from blocks adjacent to empty space

    var evt = e || windows.object;//points to event object
    var mouseBlock = evt.target || evt.srcElement;//references target source of event

    if(nextTo(mouseBlock, blankBlock))
        document.style.cursor = "default";//sets cursor to default
}

function keySwapWithBlank() {
    if (nextTo(keyBlock, blankBlock))
        swapObjects(keyBlock, blankBlock);//calls swapObject to swap keyBlock and blankBlock if next to each other
}

function selectBlock(diffX, diffY) {
    var newX = parseInt(keyBlock.style.left) + diffX;//sets value to left position of newX + diffX
    var newY = parseInt(keyBlock.style.top) + diffY;//sets value to top position of newY + diffY
    oldKeyBlock = keyBlock;

    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        if (withinIt(newX, newY, blocks[i])) {
            keyBlock = blocks[i];
            keyBlock.style.borderColor = "red";
            oldKeyBlock.style.borderColor = "black";
            break;
        }
    }
}

function keyEvent (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
        keySwapWithBlank;
        return false
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
        selectBlock(-30, 0);
        return false
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
        selectBlock(0, -30);
        return false
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
        selectBlock (90, 0);
        return false
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
        selectBlock (0, 90);
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Console errors? Valid code? I see errors in sideblocks.js. http://jslint.com

Comment: isherwood2, can you elaborate on the errors you see? I understand something is wrong with my code, I just can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using chrome to view your work, opening the tools=>javascript console will help to highlight any possible errors that the javascript is reporting.  Those would be helpful in assisting your issue.

Comment: I didn't look at them in detail. Time for bed. Just paste your code in at http://jslint.com and run it to see for yourself.

Comment: I'm using firebug with firefox and it is not showing any scripting errors.

Comment: i found it. Just didn't have my script tag to link library.js closed.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Provide an answer below or delete the question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the  section of the html code, the code used to link the html page to the library.js page is incorrect. Must close the opening script element so the html code knows to link to the library.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="library.js"></script>
```